# Rails Mass Assignment Security Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following a great [intro level tutorial to Rails](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html), and it's been a great experience - until I hit this

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in CommentsController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: article_id
```

This is how the CommentsController looks like

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        article_id = params[:comment].delete(article_id)

        @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
        @comment.article_id = article_id

        @comment.save

        redirect_to(article_path(@comment.article),
            :notice => "Comment added by #{@comment.author_name}.")
    end

end
```

According to the tutorial, writing the create method this way instead of just writing like `@comment = Comment.new(params[:comment]` and `@comment.save` is to avoid Mass-Assignment Security Error. I think this is caused by using a different version of rails because I'm running Rails 3.2.8 and the author of that tutorial was running Rails 3.2.2 as the time of writing.

Could someone please offer me a solution? Thanks

#### EDIT:

I Googled a bit and found that you can use the :as option to define a role for the class, but I don't really know if I should be using it here. I've just started learning Rails today, and I'm stilling trying to get my head around it after knowing some basics.

#### EDIT2: Migration File

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :comments do |t|
            t.integer :article_id
            t.string :author_name
            t.text :body
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you show the comment model?

Comment: You mean the migration file right? Please see EDIT2 where I attached my TIMESTAMP_create_comments.rb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to delete `:article_id` key from params, not `article_id`.

```
article_id = params[:comment].delete(:article_id)
```

instead of

```
article_id = params[:comment].delete(article_id)
```

Ruby does not throw undefined error for self-assignment,

```
a = a
=> nil
b = c
=> NameError
```

Comment: Works! Thank you very much, although I'm still a bit confused about this technique. Is it consider a "hack" or the best practice? Is passing :as option to set a role a better way around this problem?